# MongoDB use aggregate to format data from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have data in MongoDB collections as below:

```js
Users:
{ name: String, email: String }
```

```js
Books:
{ name: String, author: ref -> Users }
```

```js
Chapters:
{ name: String, book: ref -> Books }
```

```js
Paragraphs:
{ text: String, chapter: ref -> Chapters, created: Date, updated: Date, isRemoved: boolean }
```

I am trying to get some kind of statistical data in the following format:

```js
[
  {
    book: { _id, name },
    chaptersCount: 10,
    paragraphs: { 
        count, mostRecent: { updated, created }}
    author: { name, email },
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

So far, I have been able to get some data using the `aggregate` pipeline, but I am lost at this point. I have no idea how to convert it into the format I wish it to be. I can do it programmatically, but filters/sorting need to be applied on each of the final fields and it will be difficult to do that for a huge number of records (say a million).

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const data = await ParagraphsDB.aggregate([
      { $match: { isRemoved: { $exists: false }, project: { $exists: true } } },
      { $lookup: { from: 'chapters', localField: 'chapter', foreignField: '_id', as: 'chapterDoc' }},
      { $unwind: '$chapterDoc' },
      { $lookup: { from: 'books', localField: 'chapterDoc.book', foreignField: '_id', as: 'bookDoc' }},
      { $unwind: '$bookDoc' },

      {
        $facet: {
          paragraphCount: [
            { $count: 'value' },
          ],
          pipelineResults: [
            { $project: { _id: 1, 'chapterDoc._id': 1, 'chapterDoc.name': 1, 'bookDoc._id': 1, 'bookDoc.name': 1 } },
          ],
        },
      },
      { $unwind: '$pipelineResults' },
      { $unwind: '$paragraphCount' },
      {
        $replaceRoot: {
          newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [ '$pipelineResults', { paragraphCount: '$paragraphCount.value' } ],
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

I started with the Paragraph data because it is the smallest unit that could be sorted upon. How do I achieve the desired result?
Also, once I have formatted the data in the desired format, how can I sort by one of those fields?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use MongoDB as a relational database? Think about duplicating some information to improve reads.

Comment: @Yahya, the design is already done. It is kept separate in other collections mainly because the subdocuments would grow too large and go over the BSON limit. A back reference from the collection is a more efficient way.

Comment: You don't have to keep everything in one big document, only subset of info that you need as quick access. And for drill down, you can direct them where they see the original referenced document. What you are doing is just relational schema mapped over MongoDB. And it is bad!

Comment: so, do you mean there is no way to get what I am looking for?

Comment: There are ways, but won't be neat. Keep some data as subdocuments, and load full referenced documents on demand